# Angular2: Typescript и Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Заинтересовался вторым ангуляром, хотелось быстрый старт по классическому для меня пути — приложение в Visual Studio, подцепить к странице пару скриптов и сразу начать писать крутой код на TypeScript. Самостоятельно поев прилично с лопаты, [задал вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623270/development-on-angular2-with-ts-but-without-npm).

[Добрый человек предложил загрузку через SystemJS, свой пример и мелкие советы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35624623/570940),  чем многое прояснил, но он не сказал главного: как это всё заставить работать вместе.
Его пример (см. дополнение про VS) у меня выдаёт ошибки компиляции для Typescript-файлов.

```
Error   TS2307  Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\contacts.ts 1   Active
Error       Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.  ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\contacts.ts 1   
Error       Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'.  ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\main.ts 1   
Error   TS2307  Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'. ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\main.ts 1   Active
Error       Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'.  ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\main.ts 2   
Error   TS2307  Cannot find module 'angular2/http'. ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\main.ts 2   Active
Error       Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.  ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\service.ts  1   
Error   TS2307  Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\service.ts  1   Active
Error       Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'.  ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\service.ts  2   
Error   TS2307  Cannot find module 'angular2/http'. ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\service.ts  2   Active
Error       Build: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Rx'.    ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\service.ts  3   
Error   TS2307  Cannot find module 'rxjs/Rx'.   ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\service.ts  3   Active
Error       Build: Cannot find name 'UserStatus'.   ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\service.ts  9   
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'UserStatus'.  ANGDEMO U:\PROJECTS\ANGDEMO\ANGDEMO\app\service.ts  9   Active
```

Я как бы задним умом ощущаю, что нужны хотя бы тайпинги. Тайпинги из нугета не помогают: получаю кучу ошибок дублирования.

Попытки всё же вытянуть через npm пакет в надежде найти нам .ts или хотя бы .d.ts файлы привели к закономерному фейлу — я получил непонятное дерево исходников, которое и само себя скомпилировать не могло, падая с тысячами (тысячами, Карл!) ошибок.

Что я делаю не так? <s>да, знаю, связался с модными фреймворками</s>

Comment: ну вот к примеру, погуглив первую ошибку встретил ответ на ENSO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747143/angular2-typescript-error-ts2307-cannot-find-module-angular2-core

Comment: Часть таких штук разрулил, достав на DefinitelyTyped d.ts файл и перебив `angular2/core` на `angular2/angular2`. Но не знаю, где взять нужные d.ts для `angular2/platform/browser`,`angular2/http` и `rxjs/Rx`. npm  отдаёт странные d.ts файлы, они не конечны, в них куча ссылок на другие компоненты и так далее.

Comment: Нельзя просто пойти на angular.io и скачать js и d.ts файлы.

Comment: Сейчас тоже парюсь с angular2  и vs.  Удалось в итоге запустить?

Comment: Плюнул, сделав по их инструкции с нодой и VS Code.